# Wordpress plugin license issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Can i copy all the codes of a free plugin and paste it in  my new plugin ?. Is there any license issue for using the others plugin code.
My new plugin is working properly ,but for making this plugin i copy the resources of other free plugin .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most if not all Wordpress plugins use a variation of the GPL license so you can copy and paste away if you like although you <strike>might want</strike> **NEED** to mention the re use of another plugin's resources in your main plugin php file and the read me file in the plugin folder so as not to take credit for work that you have not done.

See the license note on the wordpress [website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) with regards to writing a plugin